# Would Turning off Database.SetInitializer would stop comparing the _MigrationHistory hash?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

We have a code first Entity framework approach in our applications. 
For higher environments, we turn off initializer by this way and run sql scripts for schema changes.

```
 Database.SetInitializer<DBContext>(null)
```

so when we set as null, is it required to update the hash for the migrationhistory table.. 
My question would be if we have initializer as null, would EF compare the hash in the migration history still?

Comment: __migrationhistory will be checked if the table exists and has at least an entry. we did schema migration with raw sql as well and ended up with the null initializer and deleting the __MigrationHistory table after automatic db creation.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro you mean, eveen when we set null, it will check for _migrationhistory for hash mimatch, when the _migrationhistory exists.